# Architecture for Satellite Parts of a Larger Application

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I work for a firm that provides certain types of financial consulting services in most states in the US. We currently have a fairly straightforward CRUD application that manages clients and information about assets and services we perform for each. It only concerns itself with the fundamental data points and processes that are common to all locations--the least common denominator.

Now we want to implement support for tracking disparate data points and processes that vary from state to state while preserving the core nationally-oriented system. Like this:
[image: NationalWithStates]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3353/3587038000_b0d2dacc08_o.png))</sub>

The stack I'm working with is ASP.Net and SQL Server 2008. The national application is a fairly straightforward web forms thing. Its data access layer is a repository wrapper around LINQ to SQL entities and datacontext. There is little business logic beyond CRUD operations currently, but there would be more as the complexities of each state were introduced.

So, how to impelement the satellite pieces...

- Just start glomming on the functionality and pursue a big ball of mud
- Build a series of satellite apps that re-use the data-access layer but are otherwise stand-alone
- Invest (money and/or time) in a rules engine (a la Windows Workflow) and isolate the unique bits for each state as separate rule-sets
- Invest (time) in a plugin framework a la MEF and implement each state's functionality as a plugin
- Something else

The ideal user experience would appear as a single application that seamlessly adapts its presentation and processes to whatever location the user is working with. This is particularly useful because some users work with assets in multiple states. So there is a strike against number two.

I have no experience with MEF or WF so my question in large part is whether or not mine is even the type of problem either is intended to address. They both kinda sound like it based on the hype, but could turn out to be a square peg for a round hole.

In all cases each state introduces new data points, not just new processes, so I would imagine the data access layer would grow to accommodate the addition of new tables and columns, but I'm all for alternatives to that as well.

**Edit:** I tried to think of some examples I could share. One might be that in one state we submit certain legal filings involving client assets. The filing has attributes and workflow that are different from other states that may require similar filings, and the assets involved may have quite different attributes. Other states may not have comparable filings at all, still others may have a series of escalating filings that require knowledge of additional related entities unique to that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern, which basically allows you outline a "placeholder", to be replaced by concrete classes at runtime.

You'll have to sketch out a clear interface between the core app and the "plugins", and you have each strategy implement that. Then, at runtime, when you know which state the user is working on, you can instantiate the appropriate state strategy class (perhaps using a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method)), and call the generic methods on that, e.g. something like

```
IStateStrategy stateStrategy = StateSelector.GetStateStrategy("TX"); //State id from db, of course...
stateStrategy.Process(nationalData);
```

Of course, each of these strategies should use the existing data layer, etc.

The (apparent) downside with this solution, is just that you'll be hardcoding the rules for each state, and you cannot transparently add new rules (or new states) without changing the code. Don't be fooled, [that's not a bad thing](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/soft_coding.aspx) - your business logic *should* be implemented in code, even if its dependent on runtime data.

Comment: Btw, just a note for all you doubting thomases - here (finally) is a perfect example of the value of design patterns :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: whatever you do, completely code 3 states first (with 2 you're still tempted to repeat identical code, with more it's too time-consuming if you decide to change the design).

I must admit I'm completely ignorant about rules or WF. But wouldn't it be possible to just have one big stupid ASP.Net include file with instructions for states separated from main logic without any additional language/program?

**Edit:** Or is it just the fact that each state has quote a lot a completely different functionality, not just some bits?